# How to use jq on an AWS IAM policy?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, stream, jq, amazon-iam

**The Question** - Why does jq generate lines with values, instead of generating the built-in json array? (I've tried using `[.[]]` with no success)

The code snippet @ [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org) - https://jqplay.org/s/IDhVa5KID8

**The Challenge** - Generate an array of allowed **Action**s (`Effect == Allow`).

IAM Policy (input)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:123456789012:stack/sokker-stack-dev/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:123456789012:function:sokker-api-dev-GetApiKeyValueFunction-MYDISTRIBID",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudfront::*:distribution/MYDISTRIBID",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "apigateway:GET",
                "apigateway:HEAD",
                "apigateway:OPTIONS",
                "apigateway:PUT",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

My Solution (not good enough):

```sh
jq '.Statement | map(select(.Effect == "Allow"))[].Action | if type == "string" then . else .[] end' iampolicy.json
```

My Solution's Output:

```sh
# Why is it a list of values? Why isn't it a json array?
"cloudformation:UpdateStack"
"lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
"lambda:InvokeFunction"
"cloudfront:GetDistribution"
"cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
"apigateway:GET"
"apigateway:HEAD"
"apigateway:OPTIONS"
"apigateway:PUT"
"iam:GetRole"
"iam:PassRole"
"lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
```

**Desired** output:

```json
[
  "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
  "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration",
  "lambda:InvokeFunction",
  "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
  "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution",
  "apigateway:GET",
  "apigateway:HEAD",
  "apigateway:OPTIONS",
  "apigateway:PUT",
  "iam:GetRole",
  "iam:PassRole",
  "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration"
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last part of your jq pipeline is:

```
| .[]
```

This results in the stream that you don't want. One solution therefore would be to enclose your entire expression in square brackets; one of several better alternatives would be:

```
.Statement
| [.[]
   | select(.Effect == "Allow")
   | .Action
   | if type == "string" then . else .[] end ]
```

Comment: Thank you peak! I hadn't seen your response before I posted my own answer. I've just checked and your solution works as expected, kudos

Answer (score 1):

Ok that was silly, surrounding my final output with `[]` did the trick

```
.Statement | [map(select(.Effect == "Allow"))[].Action | if type == "string" then . else .[] end]
```